# Linq-to-SQL question

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

im really new to linq-to-SQL so this may sound like a really dumb question, i have the following code

```
    var query = from p in DC.General
                where p.GeneralID == Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text)
                select new
                {
                    p.Comment,
                };
```

how do i got about getting the result from this query to show in a text box ??

Comment: I would highly recommend getting LINQPad, where you can see the results and the actual query sent.  It's a great "scratchpad" for working out Linq queries and free. http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
TextBox1.Text = query.Single().Comment;
```

You have to filter the first result from your query. To do that, you can use Single() if you know the query only returns one value. You could also use First(), if the results might contain more than one row.

Also, if it's only a single value, you could rewrite the code to:

```
var query = from p in DC.General
            where p.GeneralID == Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text)
            select p.Comment;

TextBox1.Text = query.Single();
```